# Org ref not exporting authordate when using natbib

Tags: org-export, latex, bibtex, org-ref

I am trying to export an org file with rounded brackets:

> In order to be proficient in mathematics students must be able to
> perform fundamental skills with fluency (Williamson 2017:18).

But when using the latex header below I numeric:

> In order to be proficient in mathematics students must be able to
> perform fundamental skills with fluency (1:18).

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[round]{natbib}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setcitestyle{authoryear}

I tried to set the cite style but it did not work.
Though it did work to set the note sep:

#+LATEX_HEADER: \setcitestyle{notesep={:}}

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[round]{natbib}
#+latex_header: \setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
#+latex_header: \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
```

and use citep:key for the citations.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but then I get (?:18). Is the issue the bibliography style file?

Comment: Did you pass it through LaTeX enough times? This looks as if it has not resolved the reference yet.